# Страница не обновляется при изменении данных на ней

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

У меня есть страница на которой выводятся все картинки из массива в котором сохранены url картинок. На этой странице есть иконка при нажатии на которую открывается модальное окно в котором нужно ввести url картинки, после чего при нажатии на кнопку сохранить введенный url добавляется в массив в котором хранятся все url. Проблема в том, что мне приходится в навбаре нажимать на ссылку которая открывает страницу в которой отображаются эти картинки из массива, чтобы новая картинка появилась на страницу, хотя все должно отображаться сразу же после добавления в массив

Это код страницы на которой выводятся все фотографии:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Photos.css'
import { AddPhoto } from '../components/AddPhoto'


export const Photo: React.FC = () => {
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<string[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('photos', JSON.stringify(photos))
    }, [photos])

    useEffect(() => {
        const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('photos') || '[]')
        setPhotos(saved)
    }, [])

    return (<>
        <div className='addPhotoBtn' >
            <AddPhoto photos={photos} />
        </div>

        <div className="gallery" >
            {photos.map(item =>
                <div className="img-item" >
                    <img src={item} alt="" className="img" />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </>)
}
```

и код модального окна в которой в качестве props передается сам массив который хранит url

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './AddPhoto.css'


type AddPhoto = {
    // addPhoto(url: string): void
    photos: string[],
}

export const AddPhoto: React.FC<AddPhoto> = ({ photos }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('')
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    // const [file, setFile] = useState<string[]>([]) //сохранение url картинки

    const handleClose = () => {
        setShow(false);
    }
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
        console.log(input)
    }

    const UploadFile = () => {
        photos.push(input)
        // addPhoto(input);
        setInput('');
        setShow(false);
    }

    return (<>
        <svg onClick={handleShow} id="plus-icon" fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M 11 2 L 11 11 L 2 11 L 2 13 L 11 13 L 11 22 L 13 22 L 13 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 13 11 L 13 2 Z" /></svg>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <div className="upload-icon">
                <div className="urlContainer">
                    <input type="text" className="urlInput" onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={UploadFile}>
                    Save Changes
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `React.useState` и массивы

1. необходимо передавать новый объект массива

   ```js
   const [array, setArray]  = useState([''])
   const newArray = [...array]
   newArray.push('')
   setArray(newArray)
   ```
2. необходимо передавать в "компонент контроллер" `setArray`

[подробнее там](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/4794368)

### Пример для запуска

```js
const{useState:useState}=React;var data;!function(t){let e,a,n;!function(t){t.initState=(({str:t="",dataList:e}={})=>useState(e||[{str:t,id:0}]))}(e=t.model||(t.model={})),function(t){t.Component=(({list:t})=>React.createElement("ul",null,t.map(({str:t,id:e})=>React.createElement("li",{key:e}," ",t," "))))}(a=t.vue||(t.vue={})),function(t){t.Component=(({dataState:t})=>{const[e,a]=t,[n,l]=useState("");return React.createElement(React.Fragment,null,React.createElement("input",{type:"text",onInput:t=>{const e=t.target.value;l(e)}}),React.createElement("br",null),React.createElement("button",{onClick:()=>{let t=[...e];t.push({str:n,id:e.length}),a(t)}},"add"),React.createElement("br",null),n)})}(n=t.controller||(t.controller={}))}(data||(data={}));const App=()=>{const t=data.model.initState();return React.createElement(React.Fragment,null,React.createElement(data.vue.Component,{list:t[0]}),React.createElement(data.controller.Component,{dataState:t}))};ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App,null),document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Код

[песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=6&ssc=9&pln=6&pc=17#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoUSWRYmAEQHkBZObXAo9GAWgBNcZcgHphcHgBoeFUeKkyxAMQCSADWYBRAFxwq0eMm4S4AbzgBXAM5IAyjBQwkcAL5sceQnSFoIAO0vwZla29o4ucAC8tNwUFL4oIEiWYOhOfA4ophRwOXBIAB7U8PGJyalwIBB8SAA2WeS5jXmF%20nAwAJ5gaRmR9U39cAFQOkPAvgDmEtkDjcB8Or7mIABGSFBTDQPO0-0FRW2d3fYAMsABven2ANoAujtNe60dXYNIMKfnUYYYAHT0ZykYGgABYAHm%20MB%20NjedgcSAAghhgH5QZcUB8YAA%20TH3RqyAAqNnEcAALD8AAwAajgAAoSkg%20G1zGAakgAJS43KPGjPI4oWFhKJXGpnGA6NEY4zWd6ikZvDF3Tb9XlwAD6Y2AMAFTiiNLAODAlgA-DoTJz%20kMTYMYFAxpNzU0JaKrU6AhsZs42ZFMXA0dqHdz4D5-PANVrQkgdOrfJrtb0aWYhr18PhjK74K4oiZPd6LNZtTT03Ajb6Mhi4DorombcY5jpyS4bnAUJZSydRRylS57oG4PSymgnAA3cxOM1dxoq1X6iCG3rjmaNEUBHSVao1H7p91bAMtGjB84AYVwkF8SF8Yuiv0Uh9B04Nlh9urMy4zXoiPppDsaoPMNRxE6LjkJivj8IAoGANIJta6y6IyOYfrS35AXAoIinAADWSDtBEJhzK4PomEMrigsIIoAShTRsmy2yAf0pF-hRAydo0tGNL2-YpIOcDBjaEA1KyUB9AMU4znOWbITkfoRquVS1JuGT%20nR3bKb2B7wMe4B%20Oel4Qj8N53mJj7xmY0lwi476EZJPF%20OcwqilK8qik2URmY41nCAAVJ51lwJ5cAqOo2i0gAjF6gCsIIAgiCANwggAcIHAgC8IOFcCxZFgD8IIAfCDRYAMiCAOwggDCIOFgBCIJFgDyIHAgBMIAl%20VFYAAiDxeFGWADwgaW1RlSUJUVgAMIDkPBwEVGVwAABsE2pDYlyXVYAbCDhQlvn%20blXVNbN8UJT1rLwEOKA1KOyZCJRfnCNZ6lwFcW07UgjkwAAatto4uXmIRwjSKYsShJ0oHwjK6pZwkHXAG19kgADu5ZCj8EOvoq-05GeoOij8YBWMC0FDDo52jrW8wAwjrITDAwIWb5uTShidIgxib1AWx722fAfjKL4SPwLqkZXpCijQCAGhDjpoIABL4swxyM8zGisokF6Yr9C4wydtQ6ILwui%20YMDi0gkss3kPz2FA4xvM2rYoL47TEzkJ0YzqeQbpbZtwLIgWaDoNJhXI0jKTM0q3RdNKW1Ti400BRAwOYUC%20LSoJMf9oJjMzBxdBEABEjj5DAidwAzTOq7hmfM64wiYqCyxCQXdtF6rMB%20BnviHiKaAYbhn18M4mJN6RywV34hfF-bUcHSYlv255jvBS7XqSDwnnCIHi6kdLDoz7RtEUCd8JgGAOh6Te8Yy-cJ1uVbaJgXJG5hgW-vB6H4c0pHDqohkPwjkgPyaaeOk4wEuEH1c5I3Pnfc-iPrxHAAk1gvxPNpC8bZ%20QRi-opCM-97hz07MvcgEImDMB%20EQXw1QoA3zXmAXuaYIBoCWDpH4ywqjtE7EAA)

ВНИМАНИЕ!
В этом примере используется labeled tuple elements (TS 4+).
Подробности [там](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#labeled-tuple-elements) и [тут](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38510)

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
// -,-
// -,-
// FIXME: import React, { useState } from 'react'
const {useState} = React

namespace data {
    export namespace model {
        export type data = {
            str: string,
            id: number,
        }
        export type dataList = data[]
        export type setList = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<dataList>>
        // TS - 4.0+ (named tuple)
        export type dataState = [list: dataList, setList: setList]
        type _initState = (props?: {
            str?: string,
            dataList?: dataList,
        }) => dataState
        export const initState: _initState = ({ str = '', dataList } = {}) => useState(dataList ? dataList : [{ str, id: 0 }] as dataList)
    }
    export namespace vue {
        type _props = {
            list: model.dataList,
        }
        export const Component: React.FC<_props> = ({ list }) => (
            <ul>
                {list.map(({ str, id }) => (
                    <li key={id} > {str} </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
    export namespace controller {
        type _props = {
            dataState: model.dataState
        }
        export const Component: React.FC<_props> = ({ dataState }) => {
            const [list, setList] = dataState
            /**
             * FIXME: (1) если не используется внутри еомпронента  - то `useState` не нужен
             * замени на let value = ''
             */
            const [value, setValue] = useState('')
            const add = () => {
                let newList = [...list]
                newList.push({ str: value, id: list.length })
                setList(newList)
            }
            const onInput = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                const el: HTMLInputElement = e.target as any
                const value = el.value
                // FIXME: (1) -,-
                setValue(value)
            }
            return (<>
                <input type="text" onInput={onInput} /><br />
                <button onClick={add}>add</button><br />
                {value /*FIXME: (1) -,-*/}
            </>)
        }
    }
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const dataState = data.model.initState()
    return (<>
        <data.vue.Component list={dataState[0]} />
        <data.controller.Component dataState={dataState} />
    </>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```